# When a managed SQL Instance is in a separate VNet than my application servers, how to enable geo-replication?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-network

My setup without any geo-replication is pretty simple. I have two VNets. One has my application servers. The other has my managed SQL Instance. They are connected with Azure VNet Peering.

Now, I'm trying to create another managed SQL instance in a different region to setup geo-replication for disaster recovery. This is possible with managed SQL instances.

One of the requirements to enabled geo-replication is to create a Network Gateway with the VNet of the primary database and another Network Gateway with the VNet of the secondary database and create a "Connection" resource between these gateways.

But since I already have a Network Peering setup, I am unable to add a Network Gateway to the VNet of the primary database. It fails with the error code `ParentVnetAlreadyUsesRemoteGateways` and with the message

> Virtual network gateway can not be created since the virtual network primary-db-vnet already uses remote gateways over peering peer-to-app-servers.

This setup of having the database in a different VNet than the App Servers seems like a pretty standard way. If this prevents geo-replication, then seems like I'm missing something.

So, my question is: how do I enable geo-replication while allowing my application servers and database to be in different VNets?

Different phrasing for the question: how do I create a Network Gateway along with VNet Peering on the same VNet?

PS: I've contacted support but they are taking time to get back. If I'm able to resolve it, I'll make sure to post the answer here.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know from some document, it's impossible to create another managed SQL instance in a **different region** with **VNet peering** to set up geo-replication for disaster recovery because

1. Active geo-replication is not supported by Azure SQL Managed Instance. For geographic failover of instances of SQL Managed Instance, use Auto-failover groups. Read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/active-geo-replication-overview#:%7E:text=Active%20geo%2Dreplication%20is%20an,by%20Azure%20SQL%20Managed%20Instance.).
2. The virtual network peering scenario for SQL Managed Instance is **limited to the networks in the same region** due to the [constraints of global virtual network peering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-manage-peering#requirements-and-constraints). Read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/connect-application-instance#connect-inside-a-different-vnet).

Thus, in this case, you can remove the VNet peering, and instead, you can set up a [VNet-to-VNet VPN gateway connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-vnet-vnet-resource-manager-portal) to connect two VNets in this scenario.

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft now provides global peering support for managed instances: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/global-virtual-network-peering-support-for-azure-sql-managed-instance-now-available/